# Executing exe files using puppet script

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

Hi I've an exe file (Ex: test.exe) and it is expecting some parameters like param1 and param2. How can I run this exe file using puppet script.

Ex: test.exe param1 param2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command execution using [exec](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#exec) in puppet is what you need here. I am pasting example below from Puppet documentation - and as you can see the command itself contains the parameters to be passed. In this case tar command is passed options and then filename. If your parameters are variables - you can pass them as you would ($varName I guess)

```
exec { "tar -xf /Volumes/nfs02/important.tar":
  cwd     => "/var/tmp",
  creates => "/var/tmp/myfile",
  path    => ["/usr/bin", "/usr/sbin"]
}
```

So to execute the some command.exe with param1 and param2 would be:

```
exec {"command.exe param1 param2"
    cwd  => "C:\text"
}
```

On what other options you can tweak, check [attributes for exec command](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#exec-attributes) and to understand more on behavior of execution on various environments (Shell/ windows etc.) check [providers for exec](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.stable/type.html#exec-providers)

Comment: I'm not understanding this. Can you tell me how to put my code here? I mean I've an exe (test.exe and it accepts 2 params) like I mentioned above.